# update plot after creating it

Tags: python, matplotlib

In the textbook about Python I am working with I read:
"Every visual aspect of a graph can be changed from its default. You can specify these when you create a plot; most can also be changed later."

So creating a .py file

```
# simple_plot.py
import numpy as np, matplotlib.pyplot as plt
num_points = 5
x_min, x_max = 0, 4
5 x_values = np.linspace(x_min, x_max, num_points)
y_values = x_values**2
plt.plot(x_values, y_values)
```

and running it, gives the desired plot.
Now typing in the console e.g.

```
plt.plot(x_values,y_values,'r--o')
```

plots a red dashed line with red circles at each point.
However I cannot understand why typing in the console (and not adding the instructions in the script created initially) something like

```
plt.title("My first plot", size=24, weight='bold')
plt.xlabel("speed")
plt.ylabel("kinetic energy")
```

does not update the plot.
Thank you very much.

Comment: Have you tried using `plt.draw()` after those last three lines?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "the console"? Is it the python console you are talking about or IPython console or IPython notebook? How do you run the script?

Comment: @ spherical cowboy : Still with `plt.draw()` I don't see something different.

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest : I am talking about IPython console. Sorry for not being precise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming that you run your script (let's call it `myscript.py`) by calling `run myscript.py` in the IPython console, with the `%matplotlib inline` option activated.

This will plot the figure as desired into the console. However once the figure is drawn you loose the reference to it. Calling `plt.plot(x_values,y_values,'r--o')` creates a new figure, and `plt.title(..)` yet another one.

One thing you could do is work more in the object oriented way. I.e. create the figure and keep a reference in the `myscript.py` file like this:

```
import numpy as np, matplotlib.pyplot as plt
num_points = 5
x_min, x_max = 0, 4
x_values = np.linspace(x_min, x_max, num_points)
y_values = x_values**2

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.plot(x_values, y_values)
```

then in the console you may type

```
ax.set_title("My Title")
ax.set_xlabel("MyLabel")
```

and show the figure with the updated properties anytime you like typing `fig`.

[image]

Comment: It is exactly what I was looking for. Not just a workaround but a clear and concise explanation. Thank you very much for your time!